# Keeping the data of a table while adding a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I need to add a column [new_date] that I will get from my [date] sql table to an existing table [returns] and create primary keys. This [returns] table already has 65 million records and while I could repopulate all of the data. What is the simplest way of doing this.

My thoughts are to rename the table with a temporary name. Say [returns_old] and then drop and create my new table and assign my primary key's. I think then joining the [returns_old] with my [d_date] as I populate my new table would work.

Comment: Why do you need to drop a table to modify it.  Just do an `alter table add [new_date] datetime null` and then backfill the data with data from your other table.  No need to drop or rename anything.

Comment: I need to clarify, this new column will be part of the combined primary key and is not nullable.

Comment: You would need to create the column as nullable, populate it with the values you need, alter it to not nullable, then drop and recreate the PK.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about the order of the columns since the column order can be more easily managed with a view, the approach really comes down to whether the column itself can be nullable.

If the column can be null, then a simple statement is all you need to append the column to the table. All records will be `NULL` for that column until you update them from your source table.

```
ALTER TABLE [returns] ADD [new_date] DATETIME
```

If the column cannot be null, you need to add a few more steps.

```
ALTER TABLE [returns] ADD [new_date] DATETIME
GO
-- Update all existing records so that no existing value is NULL
ALTER TABLE [returns] ALTER COLUMN [new_date] DATETIME NOT NULL
```

If the column order does matter to you, I would re-consider if at all possible (and there are many reasons out there for doing so). A few of the reasons:

- This cannot be done without re-building the entire table - a very costly move
- There is no performance benefit (build indexes if necessary)
- There is no storage benefit (http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/)

Comment: I have tried a few times. Stack overflow says I dont have enough rep to upvote publicly :(

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new null column first as this is an existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE [returns] ADD [new_date] DateTime NULL
```

Once you have the new column then you may update the date column from the other table using update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do it within a transaction:

```
create table dbo.ReturnsTemp ( keyfield type, new_date datetime, field2 type, field3 type);   

alter table dbo.ReturnsTemp add constraint NewPKName primary key (keyfield, new_date);

begin tran
    insert into dbo.[ReturnsTemp] ( keyfield , field2, field3, new_date )
    select r.keyfield , r.field2, r.field3, d.[new_date]
      from dbo.[Returns] r     
     inner join dbo.[DateTable] d on r.keyfield = r.keyfield

    exec sp_rename 'Returns', 'Returns_Old'
    exec sp_rename 'ReturnsTemp', 'Returns'
end tran
```

Depending on the size of the table and the size of your log file you might want to exercise caution with this approach and make sure your logfile has enough space to accomodate so much transient data in the log.  Perhaps perform a log backup prior.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to commit transaction at the end? btw I'm a fan of transactions, rolling them back has saved me a few times.

Comment: I believe anything within the begin...end would be implicitly committed.